# How to return value in Ajax file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, file-upload

I am using [Ajax upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) plugin to upload a file over Ajax. Its working fine, file is successfully uploaded also I can access its content in `onComplete` event.Now I want to return database id of uploaded file.How can I send database id from my spring controller to `onComplete` function?
Here is my JS

```
  new Ajax_upload('#clickToUpload', {
        action: '/portal/request/MRNFile/upload',
        allowedExtensions: ['csv','jpeg'], 
        onComplete : function(file){
            $('#progress').text('Uploaded ' + file + '. ');
                    //how to access database id here
        }       
    });
```

Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Integer upload(@RequestParam("userfile") MultipartFile file) {
    // This will save file to database and will return its id
         return id;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning id in upload(controller) function you have to **return json object** as below

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("id", database_id);
return json;
```

and change onComplete : **function(file)** to onComplete : **function(file,data)**

you can access the id as **data.id**  (key name in json object)

Answer (score 2):

Render by `echo` or whatever respresantation on file id in server side, and it comes back into your `file` var in JS.

If you want return both content and id, use

```
echo json_encode(array('content' => 'content', 'id' => 'yourId'));
```

And in js access it by `file.content` and `file.id` after `file = JSON.parse(file);`

If you're not on PHP, just return JSON encoded array with two keys - `id` and `content`.